# How to find an error in Stack Trace in PHP?

Tags: php, content-management-system, directus

I don't know much PHP, but was told to fix a problem. The best I can find out, this error prints when a non-200 status code is retrieved. I need to find where the problem originated so I can fix it. Here is the Error:  Any help would be appreciated!
[image]

Comment: Open the file `/var/www/html/directus/api/updateserver.php` and scroll to line `124`. On that line or before is some logic that you'll have to fix. Without the actual code and your business logic, we won't otherwise be able to help you.

Comment: This seems to be an older messy project. Spend 1-2 days to create a Docker image of the project that starts up with a working database, and has the xdebug plugin for php. Configure xdebug with your IDE. Then try to reproduce the issue, and step through the code with some breakpoints. In total this can take 3-4 days if you do it the first time, but you might spare months.